# Android Viewpager tinder like UI with 3D card stack appearance

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to create a tinder-like UI in android using the ViewPager.

I have looked at this library: `https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards`, but I'd like to be able to see the previous card once I swipe right, hence the preference for a ViewPager.

The specific UI detail I am looking for is:

Stacking of images with the  **outline of the next view underneath the current view**. I have been able to achieve the stacking of views through the ViewPager.PageTransformer interface, but I am unable to get **the outline of the stack of the subsequent views inside the pager - the part that gives it a 3d look** - like over here - card stacked on top of another card - http://i1.cdnds.net/14/38/300x522/friends-tinder-profiles-ross.jpg

Here is my pageTransform method

```
public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

    if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
        view.setAlpha(0);

    } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
        // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
        view.setAlpha(1);
        view.setTranslationX(0);
        view.setScaleX(1);
        view.setScaleY(1);
        view.setRotation(90*(position));

    } else if (position < 1) { // (0,1]
        // Fade the page out.
        view.setAlpha(1);

        // Counteract the default slide transition
        view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

        view.setScaleX(1);
        view.setScaleY(1);

    } else if (position==1) {
        view.setAlpha(1);
//      view.setPadding(0,15,0,0);
    }
    else { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
        view.setAlpha(0);
    }
}
```

Is this possible with the viewPager?

Comment: Hi. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @jaffa check out answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this was the way that I set it up - its a little hacky because I manually trigger the `transformPage` method as mentioned in my comment here:

[Android ViewPager manually call PageTransformer transformPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867854/android-viewpager-manually-call-pagetransformer-transformpage)

BUT, it works!

```
@Override
public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

    if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
        view.setAlpha(0);

    } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
        // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
        view.setAlpha(1);
        view.setTranslationX(0);
        view.setTranslationY(0);
        view.setScaleX(1);
        view.setScaleY(1);
        view.setRotation(90*(position));

    } else if (position < 1) { // (0,1]
        // Fade the page out.
        view.setAlpha(1);
        view.setRotation(0);

        // Counteract the default slide transition
        view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);
        view.setTranslationY(50*position);

        view.setScaleX(Math.max(0.9f, (1 - position)));
        view.setScaleY(Math.max(0.9f, (1 - position)));
        CardView cv = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        cv.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

    } else if (position==1) {
        view.setAlpha(1);
        view.setTranslationX(pageWidth*-position);
        view.setTranslationY(50*position);

        view.setScaleX(Math.max(0.9f, (1 - position)));
        view.setScaleY(Math.max(0.9f, (1 - position)));

    }

    else { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
        view.setAlpha(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not implement tinder effect with PageTransformer interface because the position value is just 1 axis value. You should have other values like touch point   coordinates in x, y axis because tinder effect uses trigonometrical functions.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do this using the Android Library Truffle-Shuffle. You can add X number of cards with any xml content inside of the cards. https://github.com/intuit/truffle-shuffle