# Android Tinder-like swipeable card stack with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, swipe, tinder

I'm working on a project which has a Carousel styled fragment implemented on it (using a ViewPager implementation of sorts). You can swipe left or right, and while the main "card" is displayed, you can see the next and previous one behind it. Then you can use the buttons below for "yes" or "no". It looks something like this:

[image]

Is there some way I can change this in order to make it work like a Tinder style card swipe system where I can instantly discard or accept cards through swiping?

I've looked into some projects in github that do this using CardView. However, when my application was originally designed, it started with the Carousel and then everything else was pretty much built around it, so this implementation isn't modular. To implement a card stack system with CardView I'd basically have to deconstruct and reconstruct the entire thing or just start the project from scratch again.

However, if I could use the carousel's current ViewPager implementation by changing the animation and doing whatever little else should be required, it would save me an enormous amount of time and effort. How should I proceed in order to achieve this? (Bonus points if elevation, shadows and card angle rotation can be done too with ViewPager!)

I'm fairly new to Android, I've been working on this for less than a month, so any help would be extremely appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try this for implementing it to the viewpager - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33669831/1649353

Comment: You found any solution ?

Comment: @Shadow I managed to implement this https://github.com/wenchaojiang/AndroidSwipeableCardStack

Comment: I cannot add this to my project, How you do with the above lib @Jaqualembo